# Les asperges dans « Du côté de chez Swann »

Tags: sens, littérature, métaphore

Bonjour,

Je suis tombé sur ce passage dans *Du côté de chez Swann* :

> « Je m’arrêtais à voir sur la table, où la fille de cuisine venait de
> les écosser, les petits pois alignés et nombrés comme des billes
> vertes dans un jeu ; mais mon ravissement était devant les asperges,
> trempées d’outremer et de rose et dont l’épi, finement pignoché de
> mauve et d’azur, se dégrade insensiblement jusqu’au pied,—encore
> souillé pourtant du sol de leur plant,—par des irisations qui ne sont
> pas de la terre. Il me semblait que ces nuances célestes trahissaient
> les délicieuses créatures qui s’étaient amusées à se métamorphoser en
> légumes et qui, à travers le déguisement de leur chair comestible et
> ferme, laissaient apercevoir en ces couleurs naissantes d’aurore, en
> ces ébauches d’arc-en-ciel, en cette extinction de soirs bleus, cette
> essence précieuse que je reconnaissais encore quand, toute la nuit qui
> suivait un dîner où j’en avais mangé, elles jouaient, dans leurs
> farces poétiques et grossières comme une féerie de Shakespeare, à
> changer mon pot de chambre en un vase de parfum. »

J'ai du mal à comprendre l'image créée ici par Proust.

Serait-il possible d'y voir une référence aux soupeurs ?

Comment: Chacun peut y voir ce qu'il veut, et les images sont aussi faites pour ça je dirais. Moi j'y vois, après les évocations poétiques des couleurs celle, poétique ou non selon l'humeur  ou la vision de chacun, des odeurs (si chères à Proust). Il est bien connu des mangeurs d'asperges que quand on a mangé des asperges les urines ont  une forte odeur dégagé par le méthylmercaptan produit lors du passage des asperges dans le système digestif.

Comment: Il y a bien une référence aux urines qui ont séjourné toute la nuit dans le pot de chambre (à l'époque de Proust on faisait ses besoins dans un pot de chambre, et même s'il y avait un couvercle, les odeurs se répandaient, et en fin de nuit l'odeur peut être très prégnante). Pour la majorité des gens cette odeur très particulière d'urine chargées de méthylmercaptan  est désagréable, pour Proust le pot de chambre nauséabond pour certains, s'était transformé en un vase dégageant un parfum agréable.

Comment: Mais je ne crois pas que la question soit du ressort de la langue française, hors sujet pour moi.

Comment: Cette question n'est pas une question portant sur la langue française et peut de surcroît amener des réponses variées pouvant toutes être acceptables.

Comment: @None Je ne crois pas que toutes réponses variées pourraient être acceptables ici.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proust fait référence à un phénomène chimique bien connu :

https://www.sciencepresse.qc.ca/blogue/2011/10/30/lasperge-change-pot-chambre-flacon-parfum

Voir aussi : https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20418/the-smell-from-eating-asparagus

Pour une analyse plus poussée du sens de cet extrait, lire :

1. *[Proust et l'objet alimentaire](https://www.persee.fr/doc/litt_0047-4800_1972_num_6_2_1951)*, *Littérature*, de Jean-Pierre Richard, 1972.
2. *[L’« essence précieuse » de l’œuvre proustienne : l’humour et la mise en jeu de la valeur](https://books.openedition.org/pub/2585?lang=fr)*, *Modernités n°25*, de Sophie Duval, 2007, spécialement les paragraphes 55 à 67.

Comment: Merci, jlliagre !